# How to assign colours on a geo map to a data column based on conditions in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop, geomap

I have data as below,

```
pincode       value

1010          null
1020          0
1020          0.2
1030          0.55 
1132          0.4
1124          0.8
1010          1
1020          null
1020          0
1030          0.66
1132          0.5
1124          0.3
```

I want to assign these values on geo map in Tableau based on pincodes. Further the requirement is to satisfy the following conditions,

- when value = null -> colour should be blue
- when value is in between 0 and 0.5 -> colours should vary in terms of red (light red to dark red)
- when value is in between 0.5 and 1 -> colours should vary in terms of green(light green to dark green)

How can I do this in tableau? I am trying to split them into three different columns, by creating calculated fields, but then I am unable to assign three different columns to colour field.

Can anyone suggest a better solution/ idea to do this.

Thank you:)

Comment: The easiest way is to define the groups using a calculation and set the colours for each discrete group manually.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create one calculated field called "pincode value groups" or similar and use if and elseif logic to set all three groups in one field.

The output would either be "no value", "Between 0 and 0.5", or "greater than 0.5"

Then you can set colors for each of these values.